# 10.1.4 michael hartl's ruby on rails tutorial TEST RED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm currently following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial from author Michael Hartl. And i got stuck at chapter 10.1.4 where the test should be GREEN but is currently RED, this is the error message:

```
Started with run options --seed 48963

 FAIL["test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation", UsersSignupTest, 1.7533403700217605]
 test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation#UsersSignupTest (1.75s)
        Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

  41/41: [=========================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.78481s
41 tests, 173 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

**This is the file containing the main error(FAIL), according to the report it should be 'assert user.reload.activated?':**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                               email: "user@invalid",
                               password:              "foo",
                               password_confirmation: "bar" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.alert.alert-danger'
  end

  test "valid signup information with account activation" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                               email: "user@example.com",
                               password:              "password",
                               password_confirmation: "password" }
    end
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    user = assigns(:user)
    assert_not user.activated?
    # Try to log in before activation.
    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Invalid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token")
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
end
```

-

You can also check my repository on [Git Repository](https://github.com/luissimo/microposts/tree/account-activation-password-reset)

If anybody could help me with this issue it would be much appreciated and it would save me precious time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests themselves look fine, but they would seem to be failing at the point when you're asserting that a user actually been activated once you have attempted to edit its account activation information:

```
get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
assert user.reload.activated? # <= test fails here
```

In the `account_activations_controller.rb` file in your repo, you have:

```
def edit
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
    user.activate # <= here's where you're activating the user
    log_in user
    flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
    redirect_to user
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Looking in your `user.rb` class, though, it would seem that you are actually missing the `activate` method entirely (it's a shame the error message doesn't seem to indicate this to you).  So, add the following method to your `User` model and try running the specs again:

```
def activate
  update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.current)
end
```

**Edit**

After checking out your repo at [the point where your tests went red](https://github.com/luissimo/microposts/commit/bbf3b986b7e747aabfbaf9f0b3e07914dbb62520), I can see now that this issue is in your `SessionsHelper#redirect_back_or` method:

```
def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
  session.delete[:forwarding_url]
end
```

`session.delete[:forwarding_url]` should be `session.delete(:forwarding_url)`, with parentheses instead of square brackets.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but i don't think thats the issue here. Im following along with the book of Michael Hartl and the activate method part comes on the next page but the test should be green right now. I tried adding the activate method anyway but it still gives a RED test. In my sessions_controller.rb i have a variable called message, i think it has something to do with that but i can't seem to figure out what it is. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: @luissimo I think I've found your issue.  Definitely an easy mistake to make :)

Comment: Just saw your comment after a while and i had already fixed this problem by now but you were right, that was the issue. So a plus answer for you anyway. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem boils down to these two lines:

```
assert_select 'div#<error_explanation>'
assert_select 'div.<alert alert-danger>'
```

These need to be valid CSS selectors as outlined in the error. They're not. A fixed version might be:

```
assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
assert_select 'div.alert.alert-danger'
```

It really depends on your styles. Remember these work just like jQuery, so they're analogous to `$('div#error_explanation')`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that issue, but thats not the main problem here. I had that issue for a while now and didn't know how to fix it. So thanks for helping me with that but the main problem is something else as i still get the same errors/fails after fixing that issue.

Comment: The other error is to do with `redirect_back_or`, though you haven't shown how that's implemented or where it's even called. It requires an argument and you haven't specified one. These messages are usually full of hints, so try and read into them more. It can be a little confusing at first but over time you'll develop an eye for it.

Comment: Thanks your helping me out big time, yet the main error is still there :p any idea what that could mean? i went through all the relevant files atleast a 100 times but i guess im turning codeblind at the moment.